# *Italic* text formatting doesn't seem to work on Android Chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, android

Recently I commented on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417090/php-include-not-working-in-my-html-document#comment25294742_17417090) question

and the text did got bold but the italic word didn't seem to get italic on Android Chrome(Latest Ver.), but when I saw from the PC browser, it rendered as it should...

I've attached a screenshot of my phone ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a bug with font files from your vendor, there's just not much we can do.

I recommend commenting on the Chromium bug report (which may get relayed) or possibly Saumsung directly in hopes they fix it in the next update.

Answer (score 5):

That has been bug for a long time, Google is working on that problem I think :) 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169446

Check this out : 
http://jsbin.com/peter/3 
You see it, like regular or italic ?

Comment: No style is italics for me on that link